# How do you Integrate IValidatableObject with Razor Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

When decorating view model properties with validation attributes, it's straightforward to then display various error messages to the user when an input is invalid. For example, the following blocks of code generate the error screenshotted below:

```cs
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

```html
<span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
```

[image]

I am trying to implement my own validation rules by implementing the IValidatableObject interface, because the min and max values I want to check against are only known at runtime - this means it's **not** possible to pass values to the `Range` attribute as follows:

```
[Range(<some-unknown-value>, <another-unknown-value>)]
public double MyValue { get; set; }
```

The documentation below suggests that IValidatableObject should be able to achieve similar results to the above, but other documentation on IValidatableObject suggests that this approach to validation is more intended for REST calls than to be integrated with .NET Core's MVC design pattern. Has anyone managed to get the design pattern as documented below to work?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/custom-validation-with-ivalidatableobject-in-mvc/

Comment: What problems are you having using `IValidatableObject`? It's perfectly fine to use, as described in your blogpost (also in MVC architecture). Make sure to map your error messages to the proper member names i.e. `yield return new ValidationResult($"Number must be between ${MinRangeValue} and {MaxRangeValue}", new[]{ nameof(MyValue) })};`

Comment: Also just in case, make sure you are still checking if `ModelState.IsValid` - otherwise the validation rules won't run.

Comment: Will a JSON error message using ModelState.IsValid automatically be shown in the form? At the moment no validation messages are being displayed and my class' `Validate()` method isn't being hit, so definitely a problem there. Also just noticed that my form inputs aren't currently wrapped in a form tag. Will do some more digging.

Comment: @nbokmans I've made some progress in that I can return the following error to the client:
`
{"errors":{"Latitude":[" must be between -90 and 90."]}}
`
The only issue now is that the message isn't appearing in the span with the asp-validation-for attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelState errors are implicitly injected into the view to populate instances of `<span asp-validation-for="<variable-name>"></span>`, so controllers need to return the form-containing view again to reflect the validation errors from IValidatableObject.